# URLConnection.getInputStream() is taking long time to get executed in weak internet connection areas

Tags: android, http

I am using URLConnection.getInputStream() to get some data from the server but when user has a weak internet connection OR the user is some where data connection is very low then URLConnection.getInputStream() is taking long time to get executed also returning the error below:

09-29 17:23:54.088: E/SpeedTestLauncher(20661): Unable to resolve host "portal.aceroute.com": No address associated with hostname.

so i want if URLConnection.getInputStream() takes more than 2 seconds it get terminate itself and do the other work. As i do not want that it show delay to user and which i can handle by showing old data from database.

so, for example something like this below

URLConnection con=url.openConnection();
con.setConnectTimeout(500);

if connection not get established within 500 millis so leave and move further.

Thanks in advance.
Yash

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
con.setReadTimeOut(2000);
```

[Oracle Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29)

Comment: thanks you friend but i already used it and i didn't find it useful because it was causing the same issue in low networks area , so now as an alternative to this i used join(2000)   and put the connection code in the thread so if the response comes in 2 sec it works the way it should but if not then it skip the connection part and do rest of the work without wait for the response    [ NOTE : earlier i was using only join() so that when ever response for the http comes only then all the other work should be done]. Thanks once again.